# How to convert array of bytes into Image in Java SE

Tags: java, image, graphics

What is the right way to convert raw array of bytes into Image in Java SE.
array consist of bytes, where each three bytes represent one pixel, with each byte for corresponding RGB component.

Can anybody suggest a code sample?

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Eventually I did not find anything better then:
   for(int y=0; y<height; y++)
   {
    for(int x=0; x<width; x++)
    {
     int i0 = (y*width+x)*3;
     frameImg.setRGB(x, y, ((data[i0]&0xFF) | ((data[i0+1]&0xFF)<<8) | ((data[i0+2]&0xFF)<<16)));
    }
   }

Comment: What are the dimensions of the array of bytes? Is it a 1-dimensional array, a 2-dimensional array, or a 3-dimensional array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you know the height and width of the image.

```
BufferedImage img=new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
for(int r=0; r<height; r++)
for(int c=0; c<width; c++)
{
  int index=r*width+c;
  int red=colors[index] & 0xFF;
  int green=colors[index+1] & 0xFF;
  int blue=colors[index+2] & 0xFF;
  int rgb = (red << 16) | (green << 8) | blue;
  img.setRGB(c, r, rgb);
}
```

Roughly. This assumes the pixel data is encoded as a set of rows; and that the length of colors is 3 * width * height (which should be valid).

Comment: so iterating through the array is my best option here? It feels that there got to be some method which accepts array as a parameter and populates/recreate the image in one go. Maybe something to do with Raster class?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, though Raster is unfamiliar to me. If this followed a standard image format, you could use the ImageIO class, but that's the limit of my knowledge.

Comment: You can also do: `int rgb = ((int)colors[in] << 24) + ((int)colors[in+1] << 8) + (int)colors[in]`

Comment: Ahh... those were the magic numbers. When I wrote it the first time I had red at 16, which failed miserably, so I went to the Color.getRGB route.

Comment: oops... sorry, it is supposed to be `(0xFF << 24) + ((int)color[in] << 16) ...`.  You need to pass the alpha in the int

Comment: Two unfortunate things about the bit shift method though, are that it handles neither the negative values of the components, or when red is >127. One of many times that it would be nice to have unsigned data type in java.

Comment: Which... now the comment about red is invalid. Bah. Though it's odd that it looks at the alpha component at all, as it is supposed to be a soley RGB image.

Comment: That way you can solve sign/unsign problem:
frameImg.setRGB(x, y, ((data[i0]&0xFF) | ((data[i0+1]&0xFF)<<8) | (data[i0+2]&0xFF)<<16)));

Comment: It doesn't seem like this answer is correct, despite being accepted.  If `colors` is an RGB array (where R, G, & B are individual bytes), shouldn't `index` be getting incremented by more than 1 per loop?

Comment: sgusc colors in the example code is storing RGB as a single combined int; which is a solution to a slightly different but mostly the same problem as the OP

Answer (score 10):

You can do it using Raster class. It's better because it does not require iterating and copying of byte arrays.

```
 byte[] raw = new byte[width*height*3]; // raw bytes of our image
 DataBuffer buffer = new DataBufferByte(raw, raw.length);

 //The most difficult part of awt api for me to learn
 SampleModel sampleModel = new ComponentSampleModel(DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE, width, height, 3, width*3, new int[]{2,1,0});

 Raster raster = Raster.createRaster(sampleModel, buffer, null);

 BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
 image.setData(raster);
```

Answer (score 2):

folkyatina's approach works if your RGB values are in B,G,R order, but if they are in R,G,B order I have found the following code to work:

```
    DataBuffer rgbData = new DataBufferByte(rgbs, rgbs.length);

    WritableRaster raster = Raster.createInterleavedRaster(
        rgbData, width, height,
        width * 3, // scanlineStride
        3, // pixelStride
        new int[]{0, 1, 2}, // bandOffsets
        null);

    ColorModel colorModel = new ComponentColorModel(
        ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_sRGB),
        new int[]{8, 8, 8}, // bits
        false, // hasAlpha
        false, // isPreMultiplied
        ComponentColorModel.OPAQUE,
        DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE);

    return new BufferedImage(colorModel, raster, false, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a setRGB variant which accepts an int array of RGBA values:

```
BufferedImage img=new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
int[] raw = new int[data.length * 4 / 3];
for (int i = 0; i < data.length / 3; i++) {
    raw[i] = 0xFF000000 | 
        ((data[3 * i + 0] & 0xFF) << 16) |
        ((data[3 * i + 1] & 0xFF) << 8) |
        ((data[3 * i + 2] & 0xFF));
}
img.setRGB(0, 0, width, height, raw, 0, width);
```

The performance characteristics is similar to *CoderTao*'s solution.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your raw data is a 1d array like:

```
byte[] imageBytes = new byte[1024];
// transform to bufferImage
BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes));
// if you want to do some operations to the image, like resize, 
// use the lib (net.coobird.thumbnailator)
BufferedImage image = Thumbnails.of(bufferedImage).forceSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT)
                                .outputFormat("bmp").asBufferedImage();
```