# Convert byte[] of RGB data to a image

Tags: java, image, kinect

I have a byte[] I captured from Kinect using OpenKinect and it's Java JNA wrapper. I'm wondering if there's any existing library I can use to convert the byte[] of RGB data into a image I can display/store?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143293/how-to-convert-array-of-bytes-into-image-in-java-se

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Java's `BufferedImage` is a great candidate**.

I would find out the color encoding scheme of your `byte[]` and transform it to an `int[]` acceptable for setting the RGB array of a `BufferedImage` with [setRGB()<sup>javadoc</sup>](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#setRGB%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%5b%5d,%20int,%20int%29). Then you can save the image to disk in a variety of formats, or render for display.

- [Writing/Saving an Image<sup>oracle</sup>](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the `byte[]` RGB data into an `int[]`where each int encodes an ARGB pixel (alpha, red, green, blue). Then use the following code to create a BufferedImage

```
int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
// do the conversion byte[] => int[]
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
img.setRGB(0, 0, width, height, pixels, 0, width);
```

You can then use ImageIO to save the image:

```
File outputFile = new File("image.png");
ImageIO.write(img, "png", outputFile);
```

Or draw the image for example in a JComponent's paint method:

```
public void paint(Graphics graphics){
  Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)graphics;
  g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), null);
}
```

Consult the related JavaDoc for details. `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB`is usually the fastest image encoding (at least it was a while ago on Mac OS X and Windows) even if you don't use any alpha at all.

*Disclaimer: Code examples have not been tested.*