# convert byte to image

Tags: java, image

why bImageFromConvert is getting null even o has data ?

```
BufferedImage img = null;
byte[] s;
ArrayList<Byte> f;
InputStream in;
BufferedImage bImageFromConvert;

public void print(ArrayList<Byte> lst) throws IOException {
    byte[] o = new byte[lst.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < lst.size(); i++) {
        o[i] = lst.get(i);
    }
    in = new ByteArrayInputStream(o);
    bImageFromConvert = ImageIO.read(in);
```

Comment: unsupported or unrecognized file format? ImageIO can only handle some default image types (like jpg or png). What image format should your bytestream represent?

Comment: thx for your response , i decoded jpg file into byte array
i want to get it back using those byte which i decoded them

Comment: I would try writing out the bytes into a new file, just for debugging purposes, and see if other image viewers can open the file. My current guess would be that something goes wrong when dealing with the bytes before they are passed to the shown method.

Comment: one image all i have, im sure 100% that o has got the values i by using debug ,should it work if i write these bytes to file ,then i read it from the file?
what should i use if i want to fill BufferedImage ?

Comment: are the bytes you pass the encoded bytes (i.e. in some format like jpg), or the raw pixel bytes (e.g. three bytes RGB for each pixel)? I think ImageIO.read() expects the first case.

Comment: it's RGB for each Pixel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

okay, based on the discussion in the comments:

You have a byte-stream which represents RGB per pixel.

`ImageIO.read()` does, according to its Javadoc, "Return a BufferedImage as the result of decoding a supplied InputStream with an ImageReader chosen automatically from among those currently registered.". So, `ImageIO.read()` typically does not expect RGB pixel bytes, but an encoding as JPG or PNG. As it cannot recognize the byte-stream as a valid image encoding, it returns null.

As possible solution on how to get an image from the RGB pixel bytes is then given on SO: [How to convert array of bytes into Image in Java SE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143293/how-to-convert-array-of-bytes-into-image-in-java-se)